# More efficient SQL apportionment view - would a function be better?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm writing a view that apportions costs across different sales departments and I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Lets say I've got some code that outputs this...

```
Dept    Type    Oct     Nov     Dec
DeptA   SalesA  10000   20000   5000
DeptA   SalesB  4000    2000    8200
DeptA   SalesC  6000    7000    4000
DeptB   SalesA  12000   4000    6333
DeptB   SalesB  8445    3880    4500
DeptB   SalesC  8700    8740    6500
General Costs1  890     5874     138
General Costs2  545      547     320
General Costs3  2674     354     214
```

and I want to apportion 'Costs1' across the sales departments and report back on 'SalesB' from 'DeptA like this....

```
                   Oct      Nov     Dec
SalesB             4000.00  2000.00 8200.00
Approtioned cost1   152.94   499.59   17.98
```

..(where 'Apportioned cost1' = Cost1 * (DeptA.SalesB / Total sales) ).

The code that I've written so far to do this looks like this...

```
select 
Dept,
Type,
[Oct-15],
[Nov-15],
[Dec-15]

from ProfitandLoss
where Type like 'SalesB%'
and Dept like 'DeptA'

union

select
'Apportioned Costs1' as 'Dept',
'' as 'Type',
round(((round((select sum([Oct-15]) from ProfitandLoss where Type = 'Costs1'),2))* (round((select sum([Oct-15]) from ProfitandLoss where Type like 'SalesB%' and Dept like 'DeptA'),2) / round((select sum([Oct-15]) from ProfitandLoss where type like 'Sales%'),2))),2) as 'Oct-15',
round(((round((select sum([Nov-15]) from ProfitandLoss where Type = 'Costs1'),2))* (round((select sum([Nov-15]) from ProfitandLoss where Type like 'SalesB%' and Dept like 'DeptA'),2) / round((select sum([Nov-15]) from ProfitandLoss where type like 'Sales%'),2))),2) as 'Nov-15',
round(((round((select sum([Dec-15]) from ProfitandLoss where Type = 'Costs1'),2))* (round((select sum([Dec-15]) from ProfitandLoss where Type like 'SalesB%' and Dept like 'DeptA'),2) / round((select sum([Dec-15]) from ProfitandLoss where type like 'Sales%'),2))),2) as 'Dec-15'
from ProfitandLoss
```

Due to the number of Select statements within the query, this is currently taking 43 seconds to run - at the moment this is just for one department over three months. I need to run this for 34 departments over 12 months! -is there a more efficient way to do this? ..would a function that stores the percentages of total sales for each department that I can then refer to in the query rather than sub-querying multiple times to get individual numbers be any quicker?

...also assume that the costs are not apportioned evenly...for example 'Costs2' is only split between DeptA.SalesA and DeptB.SalesA....I need to make specific apportionments rather than everything divide by the total.

Comment: A DBA ALERT Seems like database design issues here

Comment: All those period columns - is this a table structure or result of a `PIVOT` script?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'period columns'? - do you mean the months?, if so, no these are from a view containing a straight query.

Comment: 'straight' means no pivoting? so, there is a table where such columns are stored, right?

Comment: Correct no pivoting - I have a table that shows Dept, Type and the three months net sales as above - I am then sub-querying in order to get 'total sales' for October (for example) in order to be able to divide salesB from deptA by total sales to give me the percentage split per sales team. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of getting 'total sales' instead of sub-querying for every department and every month?